# How does it happen that an object is nested in this JS loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I cannot understand a behavior of this JS code. The `d` object in this loop becomes somehow nested in a browser console. Run the code snippet below in a browser or see it in http://jsfiddle.net/qhsjyzob/ and check the second and third `console.log` in the browser console. Why does it show that the `d` object is like this:

```
{
    Hello: {
        World: {}
    }
}
```

when it has to be like this only:

```
{
    Hello: {}
}
```

Here is the code or in http://jsfiddle.net/qhsjyzob/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';

        var e = ['Hello', 'World'];
        var d = {}

        for (var g = 0; g < e.length; g++) {

               console.log("1: ", d, g, d[e[g]], e[g]);

            d[e[g]] = d[e[g]] || {};

               console.log("2: ", d, g, d[e[g]], e[g]);

               console.log("3: ", d, g, d[e[g]], e[g]);

            d = d[e[g]]

               console.log("4: ", d, g, d[e[g]], e[g]);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused. What you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: The answer to your question lies in the statement `d = d[e[g]];`. What did you intend for that statement to do?

Comment: I'm not trying to achieve anything. I just don't understand why browser console in the very first iteration shows that `d` is nested. How does it happen? When I run the code in Node.js, the output is as I expect - `d` is not nested.

Comment: The browser console can play tricks on you because it's not synchronous. Sometimes it's better to log objects with `console.log(JSON.stringify(d))` for example.

Comment: @Pointy, no, `d[e[g]]` is an empty object. So `d = d[e[g]]` makes `d` to be equal an empty object, but not a nested `{ world: {} }`

Comment: @Pointy, yes, with `console.log(JSON.stringify(d))` it works as I expect. Strange. Thank you.